# Thread suspend() UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java, android, exception, unsupportedoperation

I'm working on a ski tracker app but I've faild at the first task :) the stopwatch

Here is my service:

```
public class TrackerService extends Service {
    private IBinder mBinder = new TrackerBinder();
    private TimerThread thread;
    private int min =0,sec=0;
    private boolean running = true;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        thread = new TimerThread();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }


    public void startTimer(){
        if(!thread.isAlive())
            thread.start();
        else{
            thread.resume();
        }
    }

    public void pauseTimer(){
        thread.suspend();
    }

    public class TrackerBinder extends Binder{
        public TrackerService getService(){
            return TrackerService.this;
        }

    }

    public class TimerThread extends Thread{
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (running){
                sec++;
                if(sec==60){
                    min++;
                    sec=0;
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }catch(Exception e){}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm calling the startTimer() and pauseTimer() methodes from the binded activity but at the resume I got java.lang.UnsopportedOperationException.
Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: small tip don't `catch(Exception e){}` without printing the stacktrace `e.printStackTrace()`

Comment: Ok, I'll keep this in my mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't ever call `stop()`, `suspend()` or `resume()` on a thread. Those methods have been deprecated for a long time, and the javadocs explain why.

You can do one of two things: 1. keep track of the timer state in your thread class; or 2. start a new thread every time you start the timer, then exit the thread when you stop the timer. The second one is probably what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot restart a thread once you have stopped it. But what you can do is instantiate a new `TimerThread` and start it again!

Like

```
TimerThread newThread = new TimerThread();
newThread.start();
```